# Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined

Tags: javascript, ajax, asynchronous, xmlhttprequest

```
    const promise = new Promise((resolve,rejest) =>{
    const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.onload =  () =>{
        if(xhr.status >= 200 && xhr.status < 300){
            resolve(xhr.response);
        }else{
            reject(xhr.statusText);
        }
    }
    xhr.open("GET","../fetch.php?s="+option, true);
    xhr.send();
}).then((result) =>{
    const obj = JSON.parse(result);
    let keys = Object.keys(obj[0]);
    keys = Array.from(keys);
    for(let i = 0; i < obj.length; i++){

        for(let j = 0; j < keys.length; j++){
                console.log(obj[i].keys[j]);
        }
    }
});
```

obj[i].keys[j]; returns undefined for some reason.
The JSON file looks like this:

```
[{"user_id":"3","user_name":"admin","user_password":"password","user_role":"admin"},{"user_id":"4","user_name":"some_user","user_password":"some_passowrd","user_role":"user"}]
```

When I try obj[0].user_name for example it returns the value.
I have to do that this way because I don't know the keys before loading it.

Comment: Try accessing it with `obj[i][keys[j]]`

Comment: you can access object properties either with obj.PropName or if the name itself is stored in a variable with obj["PropName"]